# LabVIEW 2d array iteration

Tags: arrays, 2d, labview

I am uploading a text file onto LabVIEW. The text file has a column for pin numbers

Then it has column for status of pin numbers, then wait delay (seconds), then column for status of pin numbers, then wait delay (seconds) and repeat.

So, I use a 2d String array to store the text file.

I want it so my program will:

1. indicate whether pin status is on/off using a boolean array.
2. wait a certain delay as stated in text file
3. indicate new pin status
4. wait a certain delay as stated in text file
5. indicate new pin status
6. repeat.

So, currently I have step 1 done. I cannot figure out how to loop it correctly so it fulfills the rest. I cannot get the while loop section of my code to work as I want. Picture for code:

[image: VI image]

My text file is tab delimited, here is an example:

[image: Text file image]

So, using that text file, this is what I want my code to do.

1. turn on/off the boolean indicator as shown in column 1 (Column 0 is pin number). Currently, step 1 for my code works
2. wait 2seconds, then turn off index 0
3. wait 3seconds, then turn off index 1
4. wait 2 seconds, then turn on index 2
5. wait 4seconds, then turn on index 3
6. repeat for column 4 and 5 and more if there are more (In this case there aren't)

The while loop of my portion covers steps 2-6, and that is the part I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Crosspost - http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Specific-2d-array-method-of-iterating/td-p/3169822

Don't put this all over the web (Reddit too).